# Refreshing the Contents of a Box after changing the contents

Tags: java, swing

I have a java Box in which are various components.   When the user performs an action, I want to empty the box, put a different set of components in it and then represent the box to the user.    The box is part of a JDialog box.    I am able to empty the box and repopulate it, but the display does not reflect the new contents.   It is simply a blank display (I assume reflecting the fact that I emptied the contents of the box).   I repaint the box after I put the new contents in but the display is blank in the area where the box is. Oddly enough, if I first add a line border to the box, then repaint it, the contents of the Box appear on the screen.   This is most bizarre behavior.   Any ideas why this is happening and how to get around this problem?

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding and removing the contents from the EDT? if this is occuring on the wrong thread weird repaint behavior can result.

Also might want to try

```
dialog.revalidate()
```

if the above is not the issue instead of calling repaint

Comment: Since its a Jdialog it should be dialog.validate().   But yep, that does the trick.

Comment: @Elliott: no, revalidate is correct, but you would call it on the JDialog's contentPane after casting it to a JPanel. `((JPanel)dialog.getContentPane()).revalidate();` would do. 1+ to meverett.